# Rails 4 jquery link with bind firing on reload

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

Hi I have a strange behaviour in Rails 4. I have a partial with the next code:

```
#add_tabs
  = link_to "Add Tab", "#", id:"test"
  #data_retrieved


:javascript
  $("#test").bind("click",function(){
    alert("I'm working");
  });
```

and everythime I reload the page the alert is fired. I'm completely lost.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Thanks to Pavan I realised what happened. Rails 4.1.8 uses turbolinks that manages all links on your site in order to be preloaded. Therefore everytime your site reloads your links are fired. To prevent this behaviour you must (as pointed by Pavan) set your links as remote: true in order to let them be managed by an ajax/javascript event. Like this:

```
link_to "Add Tab", "#", id:"test", remote: true
```

Also, and more important, you must use

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

And BE SURE that your application.js looks like this:

```
/= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//
// ... your other scripts here ...
//
//= require turbolinks
```

Last but not least, be sure your binding callbacks are set this way:

```
$("#test").bind("click",function(){get_products()})
```

because if you set it this way:

```
$("#test").bind("click",get_products())
```

strange thing will happen ;)

Comment: Try `= link_to "Add Tab", "#", id:"test", remote: true`

Comment: It works! But why??? remote: true is to tell rails that the link is going to be managed by an ajax/javascript function but it do not explain why without links are fired on reload... turbolinks maybe?

Comment: Yeah could be turbolinks i guess

Comment: If you don't mind I'm going to update the answer with more details and your answer. Thanks.